# change object field with upating bounded text field

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-binding

How can I solve this problem:

```
private void SetupBindings()
{    
        MyObj = new MyObjClass();
        MyObjSource.DataSource = typeof(MyObjClass);
        MyObjSource.Clear();
        MyObjSource.Add(new MyObjClass());
        txtMyField1.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", MyObjSource, "MyField1", true));
}


private void blablabla()
{
        // I need here update MyField1 of current MyObjSource object 
        // txtMyField1 text value must be updated
}
```

P.S. If only one object is stored in MyObjSource, can I use?

```
MyObjSource.DataSource = new MyObjClass()
```